# Why are distances in cosmology larger with $\Lambda$?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, distance, cosmological-constant

I'm starting to study cosmology on these beautiful notes: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/db275/Cosmology/Lectures.pdf .

At page 16, when talking about distances in cosmology, the author says that  metric, luminosity and diameter distances are all larger in a universe with a cosmological constant term.

I don't fully understand why this is right. Also shouldn't this depend on the sign of $\Lambda$? I suppose he's assuming $\Lambda>0$ at this point.

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

$\Lambda$ provides an acceleration term to the galactic expansion.  The luminosity distance to an object tells us how many light wavelengths to get back to the source, so, in the intervening time, the universe will have expanded.  If the universe's expansion is accelerating, it will have expanded more than otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I get it intuitively but I have some trouble seeing it quantitatively, take the metric distance $d_m$, in a flat universe we have $d_m=\int^z dz'/H(z')$. Now due to Friedmann equation H(z) is bigger if there's a constant $\Omega_\Lambda$ term, right? so shouldn't $\int^z dz'/H(z')$  be smaller instead than larger? Where is my mistake?

Comment: @yeahyeah: you're going into the past, so if you have a larger cosmological acceleration, then $H$ in the distant past will be smaller, not larger, assuming the same value of $H_{0}$